# Python - combine elements from 2 files

Tags: python, file, merge

Can anyone help me with this:
I have two files, say:

*File1:*

```
 A1 B1 C1 D1 
 A2 B2 C2 D2 
 A3 B3 C3 D3 
 A4 B4 C4 D4
```

*File2:*

```
A1 E1 
A4 E4
```

*Desired output:*

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
A2 B2 C2 D2 
A3 B3 C3 D3 
A4 B4 C4 D4 E4
```

This is what i got and it wont work:

```
>>>    for line1 in file1.readlines ():
>>>       s = line1.split ()
>>>        # do stuff...
>>>       for line2 in file2.readlines ():
>>>            ss = line2.split ()
>>>            if s [0] == ss[0]:
>>>                outfile.write (s + " " + ss [1])
>>>        # do some more stuff
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you replace the last line with: `outline.write(' '.join(s + [ss[1]]))` and let us know if it works (I haven't run it, but should work with minor modifications).

Comment: It works but it doesnt go back to loop through the entire file 1. It is comparing only the first line of file 1 against file 2

Comment: Yes, because you only do something if the condition is satisfied. You should handle the `else` too.

Comment: If you can use pandas, it’s as easy as using the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function

Answer (score 0):

The error I see is that you are trying to concatenate a list `s` with two strings, and that's not allowed. The correct way is to append the additional element `ss[1]` to the list `s` and then print the results. Or just use the line1 as a string.

You also need handle the case when `s[0] != ss[0]`, in which case you want to just print out `line1`.

One important note is regarding `readlines`, in that it does not automatically reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file every time it is invoked. Instead, once the file pointer has reached the end, it stays there.

Few possible alternatives.

1. Add a `file2.seek(0)` statement just before the search loop
2. Load the file content(s) in lists, and iterate over those, like:

   `file1_content = open('file1.ext', 'r').readlines()`

   `for line1 in file1_content: ...`
3. Embed the `open` file statement in the `for` loop, like:

   `for line2 in open('file2.ext', 'r')`

   Note that files are iterables, so you don't need `readlines()`.

The best solution depends on several factors, of course. I will choose here #3 as I think it's more pythonic:

```
outfile = open('outfile.ext', 'w')
for line1 in open('file1.ext', 'r'):
    s = line1.split ()

    # reset search flag
    found = False

    # start search loop
    for line2 in open('file2.ext', 'r'):
        ss = line2.split ()

        # search for a match
        if s [0] == ss[0]:
           # match found: set the flag 
           found = True

           # write to file with additional element appended (*)
           outfile.write (line1.strip() + ' ' + ss[1] + '\n'))

    # No match found: just save the original line     
    if not found:
       outfile.write(line1)
```

(*) there should be a newline which we'll strip before appending the last element. When you write to file, we have to add that back.

Also see it here: https://eval.in/994943 or a variation here https://eval.in/994944

Comment: I tried that but the first loop is not working. It is like it takes the first line, compares to file 2 and then exits the loop. It doesnt go back to file 1 to check the other lines

Comment: You are correct: two errors in my solution, I will address those, and include an explanation.